# How to sort an excel list into Alphabetical List with alphabet as header

Tags: excel, sorting, alphabetical

I have an excel table list (staff list).

I want to sort it alphabetically with the letter at the top. (refer to example pic attached)

[image: List example]

May I know if there a quick method to do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for a simple manual way of doing it for one time.

Initial data looks like this:

[image]

Just after finishing the list, add all letters (from A to Z) to the bottom as shown below.

[image]

After this step, choose sort with below setting:
[image]

The outcome of sort will look as below, apply formatting per your needs. i.e. Red colored cells are for inserting the blanks as shown in your image and yellow ones shall be retained as header!

[image]

This is the easiest manual method I'm aware of.